# Power BI Calculate different values for related records

Tags: powerbi, dax

In Power BI 
I have bunch of different types of pumps, I pay a variable daily rate for each pump depending on these rules: 
For each day:
If the pump is "On Duty" then full rate.
If the 1st pump of a given type "On Standby" then $1.00 per day.
If 2nd or more of the same type "On Standby" then 1/2 daily rate.
If "Out of Service" then no cost.

I have a daily record for each pump with: Date, Pump Type, Status.
And a related table with: Pump Type, Daily Cost

Can anyone suggest a method to approaching this calculation

Comment: can you show us some data, it will be easy to give some hints and it should not be difficult to create what you expect

Answer (score 0):

You can create metrics like these:

OnDutyPumpTotal = CALCULATE(sum(YOUR_DATASET[FullRate]),FILTER(YOUR_DATASET,YOUR_DATASET[PumpType] = "On Duty"))

OnStandbyFirstPumpTotal= CALCULATE(sum(1),FILTER(YOUR_DATASET,YOUR_DATASET[PumpType] = "On Standby"),FILTER(YOUR_DATASET,YOUR_DATASET[isFirstPump] = "Yes"))

OnStandbyNonFirstPumpTotal= CALCULATE(sum(YOUR_DATASET[FullRate])/2,FILTER(YOUR_DATASET,YOUR_DATASET[PumpType] = "On Standby"),FILTER(YOUR_DATASET,YOUR_DATASET[isFirstPump] = "No"))

OutofServiceTotal= CALCULATE(sum(0),FILTER(YOUR_DATASET,YOUR_DATASET[PumpType] = "Out of Service"))

If you want to build charts, then you can create a dynamic table like that:

Pump Dataset =
UNION (ROW ( "PumpType",    "On Duty", "Day",       VALUE(YOUR_DATASET[OnDutyPumpTotal])),
       ROW ( "PumpType",    "Stand by First Pump", "Day",       VALUE(YOUR_DATASET[OnStandbyFirstPumpTotal])),
       ROW ( "PumpType",    "Stand by Non First Pump", "Day",       VALUE(YOUR_DATASET[OnStandbyNonFirstPumpTotal])),
       ROW ( "PumpType",    "Out of Service", "Day",        VALUE(YOUR_DATASET[OutofServiceTotal])) 
      )

Replace the "YOUR_DATASE" to your dataset name and fields.